# why my bootstrap grid has too many margin?

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap in Angular and I've installed it via npm, but for some reason there is too much margin at the sides, can someone please help me?

[image: Here is a pic]

and here is the code

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">Left column</div>
    <div class="col">Right column</div>
    <div class="col">Left column</div>
    <div class="col">Right column</div>
    <div class="col">Left column</div>
    <div class="col">Right column</div>
    <div class="col">Left column</div>
    <div class="col">Right column</div>
    <div class="col">Left column</div>
    <div class="col">Right column</div>
    <div class="col">Left column</div>
    <div class="col">Right column</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

update: i dont have any css just the bootstrap css the minified version of the bootstrap installed just this week using npm.

but well i was just thinking that was something new about bootstrap, so i supposed i will setup the project again and see what happens, maybe even downloading another bootstrap version.

Comment: Can you include the css

Comment: Is it a `margin` or a fixed width? The `.container` class limits your content to ~1160px

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set full width for container, use `.container-fluid` instead of `.container`

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">Left column</div>
    <div class="col">Right column</div>
    <div class="col">Left column</div>
    <div class="col">Right column</div>
    <div class="col">Left column</div>
    <div class="col">Right column</div>
    <div class="col">Left column</div>
    <div class="col">Right column</div>
    <div class="col">Left column</div>
    <div class="col">Right column</div>
    <div class="col">Left column</div>
    <div class="col">Right column</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i know about the container fluid, but it just take all the space, i just want a normal container with a row, but my question is why it takes all that space at the sides? i know bootstrap have a little space that looks nice, but all that space is normal?, it just let me half of the website space to include my webpage content

Comment: @platinio *normal container* has fixed width that breaks at the view point. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/#containers So, I recommend you set margin using `.container-flud`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use classes like “.container”, “.container-fluid” or “.row”, you are restricted by the properties that were set for these classes in the bootstrap.css file.

So, your options are to use a regular div with a class with a different name and set the width to 100%.
The other option might be to override the grid classes of bootstrap. In that case, just use pure CSS, because if someone goes for bootstrap is to take advantages of its utilities; otherwise, better I create my grids.

The “.row” class TAKES EXTRA SPACE ON BOTH SIDES, yes, on purpose because the idea is to nest columns inside the rows, which at the same time should be nested inside of containers either fluid, responsive or the default one. Two links of reference:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#how-it-works
And to practice...
https://codepen.io/limakid/pen/zYwdJqQ?editors=1100

```
TEXT JUST INSIDE OF BODY TAG, no div, no header. Nothing is wrapping this text.<br>
<h1>Text wrapped with &lth1&gt only.</h1>
<div class="row personal-out-of">This is a ROW class out of “.container” class of Bootstrap.</div> <br>
<div class="col personal-out-of">This is a <b>COL class</b> out of “.container” class of Bootstrap, and it‘s also out of any ROW.</div><br>
<div class="container personal-text">
  Text inside of a Bootstrap container class. Note the <b>PADDING ON THE LEFT</b> and compare with the ROW below.
  <div class="bg-info row row-cols-1 row-padding">
     Text out of column. Only inside of row. No element, no class attached. <br>
    “.ROW” class takes extra space both sides; more notorious on the left in this example
    Class “.row-cols-{NUMBER}” define how many columns you want inside of that row. Only 1 column in this case. 
        <div class="d-block personal-col-child">This is a column inside a row.
      Note the padding on the left.</div>
        <section class="row bg-warning">This is a yellow row inside a row.</section>
        <section class="col bg-warning">This is a yellow column inside a row.</section>
        <article class="row bg-danger text-white">Row inside of a row.</article>
        <div class="col bg-success text-warning">Another column inside a row.</div>
     </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row row-cols-1 bg-primary text-white">This is a new row. Nothing to do with the row above, but still inside of “.container” class. This will NEST the next 2 contents.
    <div class="row bg-primary border border-bottom-1 border-dark text-white">This is a new row, nested.</div>
        <div class="col bg-primary text-white">This is column. ROWS in Bootstrap are thought to wrap columns. When you create a row, automatically get extra paddings, BUT when you create a column inside (“.col”) you remove automatically that extra padding</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
// .row-padding{
//   padding-left: 12px;
// }

.personal-text{
 background-color: #E6AFFA; /* Light PURPLE*/
}

.personal-out-of{
  background-color: lime;
}

.personal-col-child{
  background-color: #FAD8AF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you check the container class of bootstrap you can see some like

```
@media(min-width:1200px){
.container, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm, .container-xl {
    max-width: 1140px;
}
@media(min-width:992px){
.container, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm {
    max-width: 960px;
}
@media(min-width:768px){
.container, .container-md, .container-sm {
    max-width: 720px;
}
@media(min-width:576px){
.container, .container-sm {
    max-width: 540px;
}
```

This indicate that, e.g. if your screen is wider than 1200px the max width available will be 1140px. In early times, it's not very common that the screen was more wider. Bootstrap 5 add a new break-point to take account this new screen (If you're using Bootstrap 4.6, e.g. you can add it in your .css

```
@media(min-width:1400px){
    .container, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm, .container-xl {
        max-width: 1320px;
    }
```

Really I think that it's very hard read lines with a more than 1320px, but you can extend it or not put under "container" your table